# Unable to incorporate d3 in python Jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run the following code inside Jupyter notebook, but there is no d3 based network diagram displayed. All I see is a small box but no network diagram. It would be great if someone could help in identifying what I am doing wrong. I am on MacOS

Here is the code:

I am exporting a son file then using that to create the d3 diagram inside the Jupyter notebook

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
data = json_graph.node_link_data(G)
with open('graph.json', 'w') as f:
json.dump(data, f, indent=4)


%%html
<div id="d3-container"></div>
<style>
circle.node {stroke: #fff; stroke-width: 1.5px;}
line.link {stroke: #999; stroke-opacity: .6;}
</style>


%%javascript
// We load the latest version of d3.js from the Web.
require.config({paths: {d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"}});
require(["d3"], function(d3) {

    // Parameter declaration, the height and width of our viz.
    var width = 300,
        height = 300;

    // Colour scale for node colours.
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    // We create a force-directed dynamic graph layout.
    // D3 has number of layouts - refer to the documentation.
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([width, height]);

    // We select the < div> we created earlier and add an 
    // SVG = Scalable Vector Graphics
    var svg = d3.select("#d3-container").select("svg")
    if (svg.empty()) {
        svg = d3.select("#d3-container").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);
    }

    // We load the JSON network file.
    d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
        // Within this block, the network has been loaded
        // and stored in the 'graph' object.

        // We load the nodes and links into the force-directed
        // graph and initialise the dynamics.
        force.nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .start();

        // We create a < line> SVG element for each link
        // in the graph.
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

        // We create a < circle> SVG element for each node
        // in the graph, and we specify a few attributes.
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 5)  // radius
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                // We colour the node depending on the degree.
                return color(d.degree); 
            })
            .call(force.drag);

        // The label each node its node number from the networkx graph.
        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return d.id; });



        // We bind the positions of the SVG elements
        // to the positions of the dynamic force-directed graph,
        // at each time step.
        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks as though you are using d3v3 methods with d3v5. `d3.layout.force()` is now `d3.forceSimulation()` for example. 
v4 introduced a number of method name changes due to the "great namespace flattening" of D3.

Comment: so I tried using this version of D3: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js            still does not work

Answer (score 0):

There are a few factors at work here.

d3v4++ does not work like d3v3, so if you revert to d3v3, it might work.

Loading d3v4 in a script with requirejs should work.
i.e. in a cell:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

require.config({paths: {d3: "d3.min.js"}});
console.log(d3)
require(["d3"], function(d3) {
  console.log(d3.version);
});
```

And there's the other thing where the browser caches the content of the uri. So what might happen is if you, through testing out different types of d3 you manage to accidentally load a jupyter notebook with d3, the results are cached. You'll have to explicitly close and reopen the browser to test out the results. If there's a way to get jupyter notebook to send out non caching headers, that would be excellent, if not you'll have to send redirect the browser to a proxy that adds headers that specify non caching.